# Remove empty double quotes from string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Hello so I'm trying to clean a json string that i have for example:

```
      " .tagline-wrapper ":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         " "
      },
      ".tagline ":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         " ",
      },
      ".wrapper":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         ""
      },
```

I need to remove the double quotes that are empty or with white space it could have multiple white space, i tried to remove consecutive white space and then replace the quotes as so:

```
                str = str .replace("\" \"",'');
                str = str .replace("\"\"",'');
```

but nothing works, i should also remove the comma but i guess i can remove consecutive commas ignoring white space but if you can help with that too that would be great. The output that i need is:

```
" .tagline-wrapper":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
      },
      ".tagline":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         "font-size":" 1.8rem",
      },
      ".wrapper":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
      },
```

so that i can parse the json

Comment: in order to under the need a little better, could you please provide a sample input and desired output of that sample please.

Comment: Your json is not valid,. Were your getting the JSON from ideally needs fixing.

Comment: @Keith this will be read from a file the user gives so i have to clean it, i can't force the user to give me a clean file

Comment: This is an X/Y problem

Answer (score 3):

Why not use regex to search for a `"` followed by any number of whitespace followed by a `"`" followed by an optional comma?

```js
const str = `      " .tagline-wrapper ":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         " "
      },
      ".tagline ":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         " ",
      },
      ".wrapper":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         ""
      },`;
      
console.log(str.replace(/"\s*",?/g, ''))
```

Comment: A more accurate version would be this expression:  /" ?",?/g

Answer (score 2):

I clean your string and try to apply JSON.parse to convert it to an object.

**Noted**: replaceAll is available in Nodejs 15.x.

```js
const str = `" .tagline-wrapper ":{
  " padding-top":"398px",
  " font-size":" 1.8rem",
  " "
},
".tagline ":{
  " padding-top":"398px",
  " font-size":" 1.8rem",
  " ",
},
".wrapper":{
  " padding-top":"398px",
  " font-size":" 1.8rem",
  ""
},`;

const cleanStr =
  "{" +
  str
    .replaceAll('" ', '"')
    .replaceAll(' "', '"')
    .replaceAll('""', "")
    .replaceAll(",\n ,", ",\n")
    .replaceAll(",\n\n}", "}")
    .replaceAll(",\n \n}", "}")
    .slice(0, -1) +
  "}";

console.log(cleanStr);
const object = JSON.parse(cleanStr);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: It does clean the data better than the others, so +1 for that. However, you should really look into regular expressions as they can do a replace-all (with `g` flag) and you'd need way less replaces with them.

Comment: @Lucero, Thanks for your advice. I will have a look later when I have time and may update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it may help you**

```js
function convertJSON(string) {
    string = string.replaceAll('"', "'");
    string = string.replaceAll(/(\n\s*)/g, '');
    string = string.replaceAll(/(,?\n?\s?'\s*',?)/g, "");
    string = string.replaceAll(/},$/g, "}").replaceAll("'", '"');
    let parsedJSON = null;
    try{
        parsedJSON = JSON.parse(`{${string}}`);
    }
    catch{
        console.log(string);
    }
    return parsedJSON;
}

let str = `" .tagline-wrapper ":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         " "
      },
      ".tagline ":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         " ",
      },
      ".wrapper":{
         " padding-top":"398px",
         " font-size":" 1.8rem",
         ""
      },`;

console.log(convertJSON(str))
```